# Swagger give object reference error

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

While running swagger on VS2013 WebAPI project , I get the following error

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.DefaultRootUrlResolver(HttpRequestMessage request) at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.GetRootUrl(HttpRequestMessage swaggerRequest) at Swashbuckle.Application.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<>n__FabricatedMethod5(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken ) at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Steps done 
1.Install SwashBuckle Nuget package
2.Modify the Swagger.cs file to include the basic required code.
3.Run the WebApi.
4. Append /swagger in the API url.

After the 4th step is implemented, I get the above mentioned error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost version 5.2.3